# Error validating the XML content: The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

Hi I keep having this error while I try to valide a qti xml document.
Here is the xml document:

```
     <respcondition title="Correct" >
      <conditionvar>
       <not>
         <varequal respident="1">A</varequal>
       </not>
       <varequal respident="1">B</varequal>
       <not>
            <varequal respident="1">C</varequal>
       </not>
      <varequal respident="1">D</varequal>
      </conditionvar>
        <setvar action="Set">1</setvar>
       <displayfeedback linkrefid="Correct"/>
     </respcondition>
```

Here is the fragment of xsd that valide the xml

```
       <!-- ******************* -->
            <!-- ** respcondition ** -->
             <!-- ******************* -->
               <xs:complexType name="respconditionThirdPartyType">
               <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name="conditionvar" type="conditionvarThirdPartyType"   maxOccurs="1"/>
                 <xs:element name="setvar" type="setvarThirdPartyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="displayfeedback" type="displayfeedbackThirdPartyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:complexType>


     <!-- ****************** -->
      <!-- ** conditionvar ** -->
       <!-- ****************** -->
       <xs:complexType name="conditionvarThirdPartyType">
          <xs:sequence>
           <xs:choice>
              <xs:element name="not" type="notThirdPartyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
             <xs:element name="or" type="orThirdPartyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
             <xs:element name="other" type="otherThirdPartyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
           </xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="varequal" type="varequalThirdPartyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>

      <!-- ********* -->
        <!-- ** not ** -->
       <!-- ********* -->
      <xs:complexType name="notThirdPartyType">
          <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="varequal" type="varequalThirdPartyType"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>



      <!-- ************** -->
      <!-- ** varequal ** -->
      <!-- ************** -->
      <xs:complexType name="varequalThirdPartyType">
         <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
               <xs:attribute name="respident" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
               <xs:attribute name="case" default="No">
               <xs:simpleType>
           <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
               <xs:enumeration value="Yes"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="No"/>
          </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
       </xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
     </xs:simpleContent>
     </xs:complexType>
```

The element 'conditionvar' in namespace 'test.xsd' has invalid child element 'varequal' in namespace 'test.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'not'.
The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty.
The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty.
The element 'conditionvar' in namespace 'test.xsd' has invalid child element 'not' in namespace 'test.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'varequal'.

Please can anyone help? I've been trying to fix this for for a few days now..
Thanks
Cheers

Found the answer:

Ok I've found the answer. i've changed conditionvar definition. Now it's working. Thanks you all for your help

```
 <!-- ****************** -->
 <!-- ** conditionvar ** -->
  <!-- ****************** -->
 <xs:complexType name="conditionvarThirdPartyType">
 <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:choice  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="not" type="notThirdPartyType" />
    <xs:element name="or" type="orThirdPartyType" />
    <xs:element name="other" type="otherThirdPartyType" />
  </xs:choice>
  <xs:element name="varequal" type="varequalThirdPartyType"   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your schema, in your `<conditionvar>` element, either `<not>` or `<or>` or `<other>` is expected. Whichever it is, it may occur zero or more times (`minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"`). However, the `<choice>` element must be there exactly once, as `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` aren't set for it (default value is `1` for each). This is followed by zero or more `<varequal>` elements.

As I am not sure what you intend to consider valid, I cannot provide a definitive corrected schema fragment, but I think that you actually want to set `minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"` for your `<sequence>` element in `conditionvarThirdPartyType`, as in so:

```
<xs:complexType name="conditionvarThirdPartyType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="not" type="notThirdPartyType"/>
            <xs:element name="or" type="orThirdPartyType"/>
            <xs:element name="other" type="otherThirdPartyType"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="varequal" type="varequalThirdPartyType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer Mapper. This is what is valid is:
"conditionvar" can have as child "varequel" and either "not" or "other" or "or". and "not" have "varequal" as child which occured one time in "not"

Comment: My exemplary schema fragment should accept `((not|or|other),varequal)*`. In plain text, it accepts either a `<not>` or an `<or>` or an `<other>`, and then a `<varequal>` (two consecutive elements so far), and this sequence of two elements may be repeated zero or more times. Is this what you were looking for?<br/>As for the `<not>` element, if a `<not>` element must contain exactly one `<varequal>` element, remove `minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"` from that element in the `notThirdPartyType` type definition.

Comment: I think I didn't explain well. Sorry for that.
Case 1: <conditionvar>
       <not>
         <varequal respident="1">A</varequal>
      </not>
     <not>
         <varequal respident="3">C</varequal>
      </not>
<varequal respident="2">B</varequal></conditionvar>

Case2:<conditionvar>
<varequal respident="2">B</varequal></conditionvar>

In case 1, <not> can be <or> or <other>